# change the cell into edit mode when pressing Enter

Tags: java, swing, jtable

The default behaviour of JTable is , by pressing Tab or Enter to move to the next editable cell . But what I want is like this , when I press Enter I need to edit the cell insteading of moving to the next cell. How to implement this , thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Swing was designed to use Key Bindings (see the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)). That is you bind an Action to a KeyStroke.

By default:

1. The `Enter` key will move the cell selection to the next row
2. The `F2` key will place a cell in edit mode

You want to replace the default Action of the Enter key with the Action of the F2 key. This is easily done by using Key Bindings:

```
InputMap im = table.getInputMap(JTable.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT);
KeyStroke enter = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0);
KeyStroke f2 = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_F2, 0);
im.put(enter, im.get(f2));
```

Also, check out [Key Bindings](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/) for a list of the default bindings for all Swing components.